# Not understanding how root xml element is defined by schema

Tags: xml, schema, xml-namespaces

There is something really basic that I am apparently failing to understand, and I'm hoping someone can help. Below, I have built a really simple XML schema and XML document. Both are well-formed. But I am getting the following error when I try to validate the document against the schema:

```
Not valid.
Error - Line 2, 17: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 17; 
cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'SpecialRequest'.
```

I am using an online validator that I found here: http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/

Here is my schema and XML.

Schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:tns="com.example.test" 
          elementFormDefault="qualified" 
          targetNamespace="com.example.test" 
          xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:complexType name="SpecialRequest">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="content_type" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="content_data" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="SpecialRequest" type="tns:SpecialRequest" />
 </xs:schema>
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SpecialRequest>
</SpecialRequest>
```

The validator can't find the `SpecialRequest` element. I don't get it. What am I missing? Thanks.

P.S.

I took out any identifying information to simplify things and hide the client's identity. That's why you see com.example.test.

---

*Edit:* I got the following document to validate, but I still only half understand what's going on:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tns:SpecialRequest xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
                    xmlns:tns="com.example.test">
  <tns:content_type>Some type</tns:content_type>
  <tns:content_data>Some data</tns:content_data>
</tns:SpecialRequest>
```

Do I always have to use the namespace in the elements? (I think my problem is that I've only ever used XML without namespaces, and I'm having a hard time getting a handle on them.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The schema is written to validate elements in namespace com.example.test, so it's no use trying to validate elements in a different namespace or in no namespace. Namespaces are fundamental to validation: it's assumed that the rules for elements in one namespace are completely unrelated to the rules for a different namespace.

Comment: I knew it was something basic that I was just not getting. While I was waiting around for an answer, I kept experimenting in with the validator. I think I've got it now. Thanks.